# Raspberry Pi I2C pin settings keep resetting

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

I set up the pin configuration of my raspberry pi so that pin 2 and 3 are the i2c pins using

```
raspi-gpio set 2 a0
raspi-gpio set 3 a0
```

This is my configuration:

```
GPIO 0: level=1 fsel=5 alt=1 func=SA5 pull=UP
GPIO 1: level=1 fsel=5 alt=1 func=SA4 pull=UP
GPIO 2: level=1 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SDA1 pull=UP
GPIO 3: level=1 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SCL1 pull=UP
GPIO 4: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 5: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=GPCLK1 pull=UP
GPIO 6: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 7: level=1 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT pull=UP
GPIO 8: level=1 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT pull=UP
GPIO 9: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SPI0_MISO pull=DOWN
GPIO 10: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SPI0_MOSI pull=DOWN
GPIO 11: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SPI0_SCLK pull=DOWN
GPIO 12: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 13: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 14: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=NONE
GPIO 15: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 16: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 17: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 18: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 19: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 20: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 21: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 22: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 23: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 24: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 25: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 26: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 27: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
BANK1 (GPIO 28 to 45):
GPIO 28: level=1 fsel=2 alt=5 func=RGMII_MDIO pull=UP
GPIO 29: level=0 fsel=2 alt=5 func=RGMII_MDC pull=DOWN
GPIO 30: level=0 fsel=7 alt=3 func=CTS0 pull=UP
GPIO 31: level=0 fsel=7 alt=3 func=RTS0 pull=NONE
GPIO 32: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=TXD0 pull=NONE
GPIO 33: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=RXD0 pull=UP
GPIO 34: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_CLK pull=NONE
GPIO 35: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_CMD pull=UP
GPIO 36: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_DAT0 pull=UP
GPIO 37: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_DAT1 pull=UP
GPIO 38: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_DAT2 pull=UP
GPIO 39: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_DAT3 pull=UP
GPIO 40: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=PWM1_0 pull=NONE
GPIO 41: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=PWM1_1 pull=NONE
GPIO 42: level=0 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT pull=UP
GPIO 43: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 44: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 45: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
BANK2 (GPIO 46 to 53):
GPIO 46: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 47: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 48: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 49: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 50: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 51: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 52: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 53: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
```

When I want to scan the bus for device addresses with `i2cdetect -y 1` my Pi can not see any devices. If I check my pin configuration after that scan the pins have resetted for some reason

```
GPIO 0: level=1 fsel=5 alt=1 func=SA5 pull=UP
GPIO 1: level=1 fsel=5 alt=1 func=SA4 pull=UP
GPIO 2: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 3: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 4: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 5: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=GPCLK1 pull=UP
GPIO 6: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 7: level=1 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT pull=UP
GPIO 8: level=1 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT pull=UP
GPIO 9: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SPI0_MISO pull=DOWN
GPIO 10: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SPI0_MOSI pull=DOWN
GPIO 11: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SPI0_SCLK pull=DOWN
GPIO 12: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 13: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 14: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=NONE
GPIO 15: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 16: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 17: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 18: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 19: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 20: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 21: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 22: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 23: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 24: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 25: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 26: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 27: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
BANK1 (GPIO 28 to 45):
GPIO 28: level=1 fsel=2 alt=5 func=RGMII_MDIO pull=UP
GPIO 29: level=0 fsel=2 alt=5 func=RGMII_MDC pull=DOWN
GPIO 30: level=0 fsel=7 alt=3 func=CTS0 pull=UP
GPIO 31: level=0 fsel=7 alt=3 func=RTS0 pull=NONE
GPIO 32: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=TXD0 pull=NONE
GPIO 33: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=RXD0 pull=UP
GPIO 34: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_CLK pull=NONE
GPIO 35: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_CMD pull=UP
GPIO 36: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_DAT0 pull=UP
GPIO 37: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_DAT1 pull=UP
GPIO 38: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_DAT2 pull=UP
GPIO 39: level=1 fsel=7 alt=3 func=SD1_DAT3 pull=UP
GPIO 40: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=PWM1_0 pull=NONE
GPIO 41: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=PWM1_1 pull=NONE
GPIO 42: level=0 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT pull=UP
GPIO 43: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 44: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 45: level=1 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
BANK2 (GPIO 46 to 53):
GPIO 46: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 47: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=UP
GPIO 48: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 49: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 50: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 51: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 52: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
GPIO 53: level=0 fsel=0 func=INPUT pull=DOWN
```

Do you know what causes this unwanted reset?
I have actived the i2c bus and modified my \boot\config.txt to this:

```
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,i2c_gpio_sda=2,i2c_gpio_scl=3
#dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on
```

Comment: Do you use the command `i2cdetect` without any real i2c bus connected?! If so, connect any i2c bus device, or at least bus terminating resistors or just a i2c bus hub. Here is the i2c specification -> https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10216.pdf

Comment: The proper way to setup pin muxing is to use Device Tree.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,i2c_gpio_sda=2,i2c_gpio_scl=3`? Just remove that line, it's the default. Also, you do not need `raspi-gpio set 2 a0` and `raspi-gpio set 3 a0` before using the i2c bus, as this is automatically set correctly by just setting `dtparam=i2c_arm=on`. So remove that second line, reboot and then running `i2cdetect` should work as expected.